# How to remove windows

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, partitioning

I want to remove windows and delete it's partition. Also I want to enlarge the Linux partition to fill up the free'd up space. Can anyone explain me how to do that?

I installed it via windows using WUBI.
It is installed in a folder on a different partition than windows.

Comment: How did you initially do the installation?  WUBI, dual boot, etc..

Comment: I used WUBI on windows

Answer (score 0):

You installed Ubuntu INSIDE Windows (via Wubi).

To get rid of Windows, you first need to move Ubuntu OUTSIDE Windows. (on its own partitions)

There is a guide for this ([link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F)), but in my opinion it is overcomplicated.
I would instead recommend to:

1. backup all your documents on an external disk (or DVDs)
2. via Gparted, format your hard disk entirely.
3. Install Ubuntu the standard way ([link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)) on the entire disk

Comment: Ubuntu is installed In  a folder inside a different partition then windows is installed to. Will that make it easier?

Comment: @superaxander just to note, I'd judge for yourself whether you think that guide is too complicated. It's fine to reinstall, but I'd recommend saving yourself some reconfiguration if you're comfortable with following the guide.

Comment: I don't have any place to backup to so I'd rather not wipe my disk